# How to restrict Windows 8 to one app for POS

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I want to create a Point of Sale type app for a computer for one of my clients. I don't want anyone to be able to do anything else but use that app. No accessing the start screen, no control-alt-delete, nothing. Is there a way to do that using Windows 8 (or possibly in windows  7 where I can have a starting point to figuring it out for windows 8)?

Answer (score 1):

Set up your application as the Windows shell, as described in the Microsoft document, [How to Implement Windows 7 with Embedded Restrictions](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/6/D/76D6E231-8A4B-4681-8879-9884933BB8D8/How%20to%20Implement%20Windows%207%20with%20Embedded%20Restrictions.pdf). You may want to follow the rest of the document to completely lock down the system.

> To replace the Windows shell, use the following registry value:
>
> ```
>  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell
> ```

Comment: that link doesn't work for me

Comment: That would be Microsoft's fault for not implementing https properly. I've fixed the link.